# Set default Send-As address using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

Does GAS have the functionality to set the default Send-As address of a user to a sub-domain of a primary GApps domain, if the script is authorised by a Super Admin on the domain?

I have a signature script that's authorised using a token by a Super Admin on the domain, and was hoping something similar could be done to set the Send-As for users as they join.

We have several sub-domains, and users need their Send-As set related to the country they're in.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are using `MailApp.sendEmail()`, you do not have a 'send as' option in Google Apps Script. However, you can set a combination of the `name` and `replyTo` options to simulate a 'Send As' option.
2. If you use `GmailApp.sendEmail()` function, you have an [additional option](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail%28String,String,String,Object%29) called `from` which you can use to specify the from email address